# With VBA, is there a more efficient way to loop through rows in Excel, and then loop throw them twice more from within that loop?

Tags: vba, excel

My spreadsheet has a few thousand rows. Some of these rows need a little bit of data consolidated between them. I can identify these rows by the absence of a value in a specific column. Once I find the row, I need to search for two OTHER rows and then add two values from them together. The result then gets applied to a cell in my original row.

Here is an example of my spreadsheet.

```
| Subject   | Title             | Total Clicks |
|-----------|-------------------|--------------|
|           | title 1           | 0            | // Needs to be 230
| Subject 1 | title 1 | Combo 1 | 110          |
| Subject 1 | title 1 | Combo 2 | 120          |
| Subject 2 | title 2           | 123          |
|           | title 3           | 0            | // Needs to be 66
| Subject 3 | title 3 | Combo 1 | 21           |
| Subject 3 | title 3 | Combo 2 | 45           |
```

The rows that start with "title 1" in the Title column are matching rows. I need to grab the clicks from the "Total Clicks" column, add them together, and add it to the matching cell of the row that does NOT have a subject value. So for example, the row with "title 1" currently has 0 Total Clicks. After the macro runs, it would say 230 because I would add 110 to 120.

The matching rows won't always be in the same order, they could be anywhere.

I'm currently testing this code with a range that has 37 total columns and 3,624 total rows. The time it takes to complete is a little crazy. Is there anything I can do to speed up the process? My code is below.

```
Public Sub loopThroughRows()

Dim rng As Range, rw As Range, rwA As Range, rwB As Range

Set rng = Selection

subjectCol = 2 'Our first loop will look for this cell and do something if it's empty
titleCol = 1 'If the cell above is empty, our second and third loops will look at this cell
totalClicksCol = 18


'Loop through all rows that are selected
For Each rw In rng.Rows

    'If cell in column 2 in the current row is blank, continue. Otherwise skip to the next row
    If rng.Cells(rw.Row, subjectCol).Value = "" Then

        'Set two variables based on the value found in column 1. There will be two more rows in our loop that are identical in value + an extra string.
        titleValue1 = rng.Cells(rw.Row, titleCol).Value & " | Combo 1"
        titleValue2 = rng.Cells(rw.Row, titleCol).Value & " | Combo 2"

        'Loop through all rows again, looking for the first value in column 1 that matches the variable titleValue1
        For Each rwA In rng.Rows
            If rng.Cells(rwA.Row, titleCol).Value = titleValue1 Then
                'Set the value found in Column C of this matching row to a new variable
                totalClicks1 = rng.Cells(rwA.Row, totalClicksCol).Value
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        'Loop through all rows again, looking for the first value in column 1 that matches the variable titleValue2
        For Each rwB In rng.Rows
            If rng.Cells(rwB.Row, titleCol).Value = titleValue2 Then
                'Set the value found in Column C of this matching row to a new variable
                totalClicks2 = rng.Cells(rwB.Row, totalClicksCol).Value
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        'Add together the two values we found from the two above loops and set it as the value of column 18 in the row of our original loop
        rng.Cells(rw.Row, totalClicksCol).Value = totalClicks1 + totalClicks2

    End If

Next

Debug.Print "Done!"

End Sub
```

Comment: Apart from the obvious suggestion of just doing a `SUMIF`, or the less obvious suggestion of reading the data into an array and performing the processing using the array, your code could be written to go through the rows once creating totals of all the "titles" (stored, for instance, in a Dictionary, or just in an array), and then go through the rows a second time placing those totals at the appropriate spots.  That would reduce the processing to 2*rows, instead of rows^2.

Comment: Maybe `SUMIFS` if both the first and second column denote uniqueness.

Answer (score 2):

Start with this.

[image]

Run this.

```
Option Explicit

Sub wqewwqwqwq()
    With Worksheets("Sheet4")
        With .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(0, -3))
            With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
                Debug.Print .Address(0, 0)
                .Offset(0, 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(C4, C2, RC2, C1, ""<>"")"
            End With
            'optionally revert formulas to values
            .Offset(0, 3).Value = .Offset(0, 3).Value2
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

End up with this.

[image]

Comment: This is beautiful, I was almost done with a code that looked *amazingly* similar :D. I guess this should be fastest because it uses Excel's built-ins to max.

Comment: @A.S.H - Yes, I find your coding style very similar to my own, albeit with significantly different naming conventions.

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this...
The code below assumes that Row1 is header row where column A is Subject, Column B is Title and Column D is Total Clicks.

```
Sub GetTotalClicksTitleWise()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, vCell As Range
Dim Title As String
Dim TotalClick As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ws = ActiveSheet
lr = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
'Assuming Column B is the Title Column
Set rng = ws.Range("B2:B" & lr)
For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value <> Title Then
        Title = cell.Value
        With ws.Rows(1)
            .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=Title
            TotalClick = Application.Sum(ws.Range("D2:D" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
            For Each vCell In ws.Range("D2:D" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                If vCell.Value = 0 And ws.Cells(vCell.Row, "A") = "" Then
                    vCell.Value = TotalClick
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next vCell
        End With
    End If
    TotalClick = 0
Next cell
ws.AutoFilterMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, the rate limiting step in VBA is the transfer of values between VBA and the worksheet. So any line such as

```
.Range("MyRange").Cells(1,1).Value = "SomeValue"
```

or

```
myVariable = .Range("MyRange").Cells(1,1).Value
```

will be a bottleneck.

As YowE3K mentioned, read the values from the range into a variant. They will be copied into the variant as a base 1, two dimensional variant array. Then process the array. Then you can set the results back on the sheet if required.

For example:

```
Public Sub ProcessRange()
    Dim rngMyRange As Range
    Dim vntMyRangeValues As Variant
    Dim intRowCounter As Integer
    Dim intRowCount As Integer

    Dim strConcatenation As String

    Set rngMyRange = wksOne.Range("MyNamedRange")
    vntMyRangeValues = rngMyRange.Cells.Value
    intRowCount = UBound(vntMyRangeValues)

    For intRowCounter = 1 To intRowCount
        'Some random processing to illustrate the point
        strConcatenation = CStr(vntMyRangeValues(intRowCounter, 1)) & " - " & CStr(vntMyRangeValues(intRowCounter, 2))
        Debug.Print strConcatenation
        vntMyRangeValues(intRowCounter, 3) = strConcatenation
    Next

    'the fast way to save the result values on the sheet
    rngMyRange.Cells.Value = vntMyRangeValues
End Sub
```

This alternative approach will radically speed up any loops that continually get or set values to/from VBA variables.